# list processes running inside of screen (manager with with VT100/ANSI terminal emulation)

Tags: process, gnu-screen

I have an application that during installation runs a bunch of processes via screen, so I can see those if attached to the screen, however I don't see those via "ps -ef" or "ps auxww". How can I list all the processes running inside of screen ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
start cmd: # screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        24525.pts-0.syscontrol  (Attached)
start cmd: # pstree -p 24525
screen(24525)─┬─bash(10773)───su(10790)───bash(10791)
              ├─bash(10863)───pstree(11099)
              └─bash(24526)
```

Comment: Installation of `pstree` on Linux: `apt-get install psmisc` (Debian) or `yum install psmisc` (CentOS)

Answer (score 1):

Using `pstree` greatly simplifies the problem, but some clarification might help.

When you start `screen`, it runs two processes, `screen` (the parent) and `SCREEN` (the child):

- The `-ls` option of `screen` shows the session identifier with the child's process-id.
- You should list the parent process-id for consistency.
- It helps to show the argument list; `pstree` can do this.
- You could have multiple screen sessions on the same machine.

Tying these together calls for a script.  Here is an example:

```
# $Id: ps-screen,v 1.1 2016/10/23 22:19:56 tom Exp $
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172347/list-processes-running-inside-of-screen-manager-with-with-vt100-ansi-terminal-e
screen -ls | awk '/[0-9]+\./{print;}' | while read session
do
    child=$(echo "$session" | awk '{sub("\..*","",$1); print $1;}')
    printf '%s\n' "$session"
    parent=$(ps -p $child -o ppid=)
    pstree -p -a $parent
done
```

and example output, for two sessions:

```
~ (101) ps-screen 
38142.pts-1.vmw-debian7-64      (10/23/2016 06:20:28 PM)        (Attached)
screen,38141
  └─screen,38142
      └─tcsh,38143
          └─ps-screen,38161 /users/tom/bin/ps-screen
              └─ps-screen,38164 /users/tom/bin/ps-screen
                  └─pstree,38169 -p -a 38141
3975.pts-0.vmw-debian7-64       (10/23/2016 06:15:28 AM)        (Attached)
screen,3974
  └─screen,3975
      ├─tcsh,5002
      │   └─ded,19926 /usr/build//ncurses
      │       └─vile,24647 /usr/build/ncurses/ncurses-6.0-20161029/NEWS
      └─tcsh,36551
          └─ded,36569 /tmp
```

Further reading:

- [pstree - display a tree of processes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pstree.1.html) (Linux)
- [pstree - display a tree of processes](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pstree&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%207.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&format=html) (FreeBSD)

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve tty(pty) from `screen -ls` and then, `ps -t ttyname` or `ps t ttyname` will display process list associated with ttyname.

[ps(1) manpage on Ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/ps.1.html)
[screen(1) manpage on Ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/screen.1.html)